# Cannot convert from nvarchar to int when there are variables in where clause

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, where-clause

```
select @now_total = COUNT(*) 
from CountTable 
where quotename(CHAR(65 + @i - 1)) > 0 ;
```

I wrote this in SQL Server in order to get the number of rows where the value in column 'A', B' ... 'Z' is greater than 0 respectively. But SQL Server tells me

> cannot convert from nvarchar to int

I tried to change the `quotename` to just `[A]>0`, that's ok. But I have to calculate for i=1...26. What's the correct statement for this?

Thank you!

Comment: Looks like there's something wrong with your schema. Columns named from `A` to `Z` is a bad sign..

Comment: Try using dynamic SQL instead.

Comment: Well, this table is for specific use, so I used these names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you cannot specify the columns dynamically using plain SQL. What happens here is that `quotename(CHAR(65))` gets converted to `[A]`. But instead of using the column `A`, it's being treated as a literal. Hence, the error:

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '[A]' to data
>   type int.

You should use dynamic sql:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1),
    A INT,
    B INT
)
INSERT INTO tbl(A, B) VALUES
(1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 2), (2, 3);

DECLARE @now_total INT
DECLARE @i INT = 1
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @sql = 'SELECT @now_total = COUNT(*) FROM tbl WHERE ' + QUOTENAME(CHAR(65 + @i - 1) ) + ' > 0'
EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@now_total INT OUT', @now_total OUT

SELECT @now_total

DROP TABLE tbl
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked perfectly. I'm new to dynamic SQL statements, your answer helped me a lot.

Comment: No problem. You may want to read @Blogbeard's answer. His suggestion to restructure your table would be better than using dynamic sql.

Answer (score 1):

You can't specify a column name dynamically in the middle of a SQL statement like that.

You *can* construct a string containing a SQL statement and then execute it:

```
declare @now_total int
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
set @sql = 
   'select @now_total = count(*) from CountTable where ' + quotename(char(64+@i)) + ' > 0;'
exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@now_total int output', @now_total output;
```

As you can see, that's not a lot of fun.

It would be better to change your table structure from

```
create table CountTable (A int, B int, C int, ...)    
insert CountTable values (1, 34, 0, ..)
```

To something like

```
create table CountTable (CountId int, ValueId char(1), Count int)
insert CountTable values (1, 'A', 1)
insert CountTable values (1, 'B', 34)
insert CountTable values (1, 'C', 0)
...
```

Then your query becomes

```
select count(distinct CountId) from CountTable where ValueId=char(64+@i) and Count>0
```

And you don't have to use dynamic SQL.

Comment: Thank you for your alternative idea! In fact, this table is generated from the last query so it will be hard to change the schema of it. The original form is a matrix full of uppercase letters, and my target is to calculate the appearance rate for each letter. So I first do the query to generate the table described in the problem, and then calculate the appearance rate for each letter.